# how to turn off useUTC in angular2-highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

how to turn off useUTC in angular2-highcharts?

In normal jquery + highcharts, I can use

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in app.module.ts or the component you are using angular2-highcharts add:

```
const Highcharts = require('highcharts');
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

I found out that adding codes above to app.module.ts will not affect the component using angular2-highcharts.

see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#add-highcharts-modules